# MDX Multi-Valued Parameters from Database Query

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, mdx

This is my first StackOverflow question so I appreciate any help that you can give.

**Current Situation** We have a series of SSRS reports that are deployed to SharePoint running in SharePoint integrated mode.  I'm trying to create data driven SharePoint subscriptions using data from an Oracle database that pass report parameters to SSRS reports that run against an analysis server cube.

**The Problem** I have everything working except when I need to provide a multi-valued parameter to the report.

Here's the underlying MDX for the report:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Units Sold]} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { (
[PTOC Dates].[Broadcast Dates].[Bcst Week].ALLMEMBERS * 
[Price Type Groups].[Price Group ID].[Price Group ID].ALLMEMBERS * 
[Price Type Groups].[Price Type Group].[Price Type Group].ALLMEMBERS * 
[Dayparts].[Network].[Network].ALLMEMBERS ) } 
ON ROWS 
FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DaypartsNetworkDayparts, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@NetworkNetwork, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@AirDatesBroadcastYrQtr, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Inventory])))
WHERE ( 
[Air Dates].[Broadcast Yr Qtr].currentmember, 
[Network].[Network].currentmember, 
[Dayparts].[Network Dayparts].currentmember )
```

The offending multi-valued parameter is @DaypartsNetworkDayparts.

The query from the database returns 2 variations, single valued and multi-valued. Note that they are fully qualified MDX syntax and I used a comma to delimit the multi-valued parameter. (I left out other fields for clarity).

```
DaypartsNetworkDayparts Parameter
---------------------------------
[Dayparts].[Network Dayparts].[Daypart Listname].&[3]&[25]

[Dayparts].[Network Dayparts].[Daypart Listname].&[3]&[25],[Dayparts].[Network Dayparts].[Daypart Listname].&[3]&[26]
```

Next I created a SharePoint data driven subscription that uses this data to generate reports. The first line works perfectly - a report is generated using the correct parameter. The second fails with the following error:

Default value or value provided for the report parameter 'DaypartsNetworkDayparts' is not a valid value.;

Using SSMS, I manually replaced the parameter line with this:

```
FROM ( SELECT ({[Dayparts].[Network Dayparts].[Daypart Listname].&[3]&[25],
[Dayparts].[Network Dayparts].[Daypart Listname].&[3]&[26]} ) ON COLUMNS
```

It works great because it's a well defined set.

So the problem is in the syntax of passing the comma-delimited list into @DaypartsNetworkDayparts parameter.

Can anyone help me out with the correct syntax to have the MDX query accept multiple values?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cant use comma separated values in that way, you need to create each value which you want to pass with the whole hierarchy.
Example:
Your values are: {1,2,3}
to work it properly in mdx you need to pass them as a :

```
[Dayparts].[Network Dayparts].[Daypart Listname].[1],
```

[Dayparts].[Network Dayparts].[Daypart Listname].[2],
[Dayparts].[Network Dayparts].[Daypart Listname].[3],

value passed to strtoset(@) need to have format as above - this is CSV in MDX world...

to do that you need to:
Create hidden parameter which will have default value of :
="[Dayparts].[Network Dayparts].[Daypart Listname].[" & @DaypartsNetworkDayparts & "]"
depend on the format of the @DaypartsNetworkDayparts you may need to use convertion functions to match the formats.
and then insert that hidden parameter in your mdx strtoset(@yourhiddenparameter)
Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Daniel - I see two parts to your answer.  The first is the way the 


[Dayparts].[Network Dayparts].[Daypart Listname].&[3]&[25]

Comment: I'm bit confused with your comment :) - Is your problem sorted now ?

Comment: Still a confused. The param with &[3]&[25] is a compound key. Thinking this might be the issue, I created a simpler version but had the same problem. Ne version:

Comment: SELECT NON EMPTY { 
   [Measures].[Potential Units Sold] } ON COLUMNS, 
   NON EMPTY { (
   [Air Dates].[Broadcast Yr Qtr].[Bcst Qtr].ALLMEMBERS * 
   [Network].[Network].[Network].ALLMEMBERS ) } ON ROWS 
   FROM ( 
   SELECT ( { 
   [Air Dates].[Broadcast Yr Qtr].[Bcst Year].&[2014] } ) ON COLUMNS 
   FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@NetworkNetwork, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
   FROM [Inventory]))

Comment: Parameter line is FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@NetworkNetwork, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS.  In SSMS, I replace it with FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET("{[Network].[Network].&[3],[Network].[Network].&[4]}", CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS and it works. So I need to figure out how to send the string "{[Network].[Network].&[3],[Network].[Network].&[4]}" (including the double quotes) to the parameter. Thanks!

Comment: Brad - Did you try to do it with the hidden parameter as I explained before ?

Comment: Brad - Did you try to do it with the hidden parameter as I explained before ? Also regarding your error message "Default value or value provided for the report parameter 'DaypartsNetworkDayparts' is not a valid value" - where did you declared default value ? Is this been done in query designer in Visual Studio ? Did you tick the multivalue properties ?

Comment: Can't seem to make the hidden param work. SSRS won't let me use the "[Dayparts].[Network Dayparts].[Daypart Listname].[" & @DaypartsNetworkDayparts & "]" syntax.  If I just use DaypartsNetworkDayparts, the hidden param works but the report dataset rejects the (at)HiddenDaypartParam. The param is a string.

Comment: As for your other questions: the default param is defined in the report dataset and the multi-value parameter box is checked.

Comment: I've found several sources that indicate that multi-value params are not supported. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8ab615b4-1373-4258-bf49-c2843cfea8e9/ssrs-data-driven-subscriptions?forum=sqlreportingservices. All sources are Microsoft. I'm very annoyed, this seems like a standard thing to have. The only work around I see is this hidden param solution.